# Exploiting similarity of triangles to express one length in terms of all the rest.

Tags: geometry

I need to express the length $h$ in the depicted figure as a function of the length $D$ (the expression may contain the other parameters as well, except X). The circle $ACEA$ has radius $R+r$ and centre $P$. The circle $ECE$ has radius $R_{s}-r$ and centre $Q$. That is all that is known.  I tried without success to use the similarity of the two right-angles triangles of heights $2r-D$ and $2r-D+h$. Any help would be appreciated. Please note that the point $Q$ is **not** on the circle $ACEA$.

[image]

Comment: If the upper right side (for which, sadly, you didn't provide a name) can be at any angle to vertical, then the answer can be anything. If it must be at some specific angle to vertical, then what is it?

Comment: What parameters are known exactly. Which segments are known, which angles are known, which triangles are right angled... You have to give us all the information and not let us guess. What you have on the picture doesn't tell me anything. It tells me that most likely you are wasting your time.

Comment: You have not brought all the segment length relations properly together. Are there right angles? like ACQ ? isosceles triangles? PA=PC? I have labelled some points for further solution. As posed your query may be voted for removal.

Comment: @IvanNeretin : I have added the full geometry of the problem now.

Comment: @Futurologist :All the known segments and angles are indicated on the figure. All indicated information is known exactly. I edited the figure, and I hope now it doesn't give you the impression that I'm wasting my time.

Comment: @Narasimham : I edited the figure to include all that is known about the problem. If the question still looks worthless to the forum, you may remove it.

Comment: Thank you, that's much better. Now, are the biomolecules, Java, and Monte Carlo all that relevant to the problem at hand?

Comment: @IvanNeretin :I wouldn't imagine so. It was just to share the atmosphere behind the problem, but in case the mentioning of those terms brings about any inconvenience, I have removed them from the problem statement.

Comment: Good. Would be also good to clear your notation of the unnecessary complications and just let the huge circle have radius $R$, and the small one $r$, but... whatever. Well, now we see that ACQ is also a right triangle, which is similar to ABC and also to the smaller one with side $2r-D$. This should suffice.

Comment: @IvanNeretin : I don't think ACQ is a right triangle. That would only be the case if the point Q was on the circle ACEA.

Comment: Wait, is it not? Well, then things get a bit hairy.

Comment: @IvanNeretin :Q is not on the circle, and now I have added that to the problem statement as well.

Answer (score 1):

$AQ = PQ + PA = PQ + (R+r) = (R_s - r) + (2r - D)$ solve for $PQ$

$PQ = R_s-r + 2r-D - R-r = R_s - D -R.$ Cosine theorem for triangle $PQC$
$$(R+r)^2 = (R_s - D -R)^2 + (R_s-r)^2 - 2 \, (R_s - D -R) (R_s-r) \cos(\alpha) $$
where $\alpha = \angle \, PQC$. Then $BC = (R_s - r) \sin(\alpha)$ and $BQ = (R_s - r) \cos(\alpha)$. Power of a point in a circle $$BC^2 = h \, (BQ + R_s-r)$$ so $$h = \frac{BC^2}{BQ + R_s-r}  = \frac{(R_s - r)^2 \sin^2(\alpha)}{ (R_s - r) \cos(\alpha) + R_s-r} = \frac{(R_s - r)^2 (1-\cos^2(\alpha))}{ (R_s - r) \cos(\alpha) + R_s-r}$$ Finally 
$$h =  \frac{(R_s - r)^2 -(R_s - r)^2 \cos^2(\alpha)}{(R_s - r) \cos(\alpha) + R_s-r}$$ where 
$$ (R_s-r) \cos(\alpha) =\frac{(R_s - D -R)^2 + (R_s-r)^2 - (R+r)^2} { 2 \, (R_s - D -R)} $$
If I haven't made too many mistakes, the final answer is
$$h =  \frac{4 \,(R_s - D -R)^2(R_s - r)^2 -\Big((R_s - D -R)^2 + (R_s-r)^2 - (R+r)^2\Big)^2}{2\,(R_s - D -R)\Big((R_s - D -R)^2 + (R_s-r)^2 - (R+r)^2\Big) + 4 \, (R_s-r)(R_s - D -R)^2}$$ which should be a piece of cake for a computer :D

I think this settles it.

Comment: @2good4this Was this what you were asking for? Was this the formula you needed?